# market:// links broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, linking

As seen in [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/45/is-there-a-good-app-for-monitoring-the-amount-of-data-traffic/129#129), the link:

> ```
> market://search?q=pname:com.trafficstats
> ```

...has been turned into:

> ```
> http://market//search?q=pname%3acom.trafficstats
> ```

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71108/links-with-uris-of-schemes-other-than-http-https-are-broken

Answer (score 4):

We don't support any form of link except `http://` and `https://`and `ftp://`

edit: this has been enabled as a site-specific renderer for android.se. You will have to re-save any affected posts, however -- but all new posts will behave as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Jeff.  Would it be possible to change that for the Android.SE and allow for `market://` links?

Comment: @matt possibly -- how many posts would benefit?

Comment: Almost any question regarding apps currently links to the Market scraping websites like AppBrain, AndroLib, Cyrket. Pretty much any question linking to those sites would benefit from a direct Market link.

Comment: I don't know.  It all depends on how many people are browsing the site from their Android devices.  I'd say a large majority of the posts make reference to an app in one way or another.  A direct market link would be helpful in all those cases for people browsing on their phones, but are useless to those accessing the site on a non-android device.

Comment: @Matt,@GAThrawn: Would it be possible to have a Market URL format, such that when you browse in Android, the URL will turn into a Market link but when browsing on non-Android device, it will turn into a regular link to AppBrain/AndroLib/Cyrket/etc and/or perhaps QR barcode?

Answer (score 3):

Now that the Market has launched as a website explicitly available to both phones and PCs, where the http://market.android.com/.... link will take you to the webpage on a PC, or straight into the relevant page in the Market app on a phone, this probably isn't necessary any more.

See also [QR Code generator](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310/qr-code-generator)