# QR Code generator

Tags: feature-request, qr-codes, market, editing

Hey guys,

Now that the [Android Market](https://market.android.com/) is out on the web it would be great to be able to generate a QR code right here in text box. This would allow us to stop using other websites like AppBrain for our app linking.

Does anyone know if the [WMD editor](http://wmd-editor.com/) used here can be modified to add a tool?

Answer (score 4):

We can now at least use direct links to Market apps that use a normal URL scheme and will work as links on both the phone and your PC.

No need to use a market://.... link, we can use  http://market.android.com/....

Eg this link should take you to the app's Market page on a normal web browser, and if clicked from an Android browser should take you into the app's page in the Market app:

http://market.android.com/details?id=com.rovio.angrybirds

What's more the Android market web pages even have a QR code on them. Anyone know if there'd be a problem embedding the QRs from the Market server in here, they use the normal Ggoogle Charts API to create the QR, like this:

http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=100x100&chld=|0&cht=qr&chl=http%3A%2F%2Fmarket.android.com%2Fdetails%3Fid%3Dcom.rovio.angrybirds

Which in an image link gives us:

[image]

Which should all be a lot more useful (and less confusing to the casual visitor) than sending someone to Appbrain, or the like.

Comment: I wouldn't expect using the Market QR codes would be a problem at all. Better to go to the source when possible.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's necessary. For one thing it's not a change that would be all that universal. What use would, say, English.SE have for QR codes?

Besides, the new web market puts QR codes right on the page. It's only a couple of clicks to get the URL for the image and add it to a message.

[image: cropped image from the Android Market website]

Comment: Is it just me but I can't see the QR codes on the app detail pages?

Comment: I see them in the right panel right under the price.

Comment: (added a screen shot)

Comment: There are various SE sites that have their own tweaks, it doesn't need to be universal.  And I can definitely see the odd case where a "Learn English on the Go" app or something is linked from English.SE.

Comment: I don't see the QR code. Must be limited to US only or something.

Comment: Ok I finally see the QR code... weird. No need for the QR code implementation then :)

Comment: Plus when you go to the page there's a link to install the app on your phone so you don't even have to take your phone out of your pocket.  To be honest, I think QR codes are kinda cool but I never use them.